# How can I create blog specific database table in multisite?

Tags: multisite, database, activation

I am creating a plugin, that supposed to work on WP multisite yesterday. I've installed WP multisite on my server. While testing I found out that `register_activation_hook` created 1 table on the main blog only, while I have 2 more blogs.

Here is how I create the tables now:

```
global $wpdb;
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "pm_services";
$table = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
  ID bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  service_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY cuunique (`ID`)
  );";
dbDelta($table);
```

Is there a way to creating this table for every blog on the network upon activation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic process - on activation, check if [`is_multisite`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_multisite), get all of the sites with [`wp_get_sites`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites), loop over the results with `foreach` and [`switch_to_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) for each site ID, and create the table.

You'll also need to hook the `wpmu_new_blog` action, check if [`is_plugin_active_for_network`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active_for_network), switch to that blog ID and run your activation code, so sites added after activation have their table created. Don't forget to switch back to the original blog ID after you run your activation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. so, basically in `register_activation_hook` i'll check for multi site, and run through the blogs and create one for each, but what did you mean about `wpmu_new blog` ?

Comment: After your plugin is activated, new blogs can be created, so your activation code has to run or those new blogs won't have their own table.

Comment: yea make sense.. so the table that was created for the network is available for everyone ? i mean right now on my db i see the tables i create without blog number prefix.. if they are accessible to the whole network, how do i access them ? to what blog do i switch ?

Comment: no, that table is just for the main site. additional sites have table prefixes starting at 2. The main site is typically 1, but the main site tables don't have that prefix, as you can create a network on top of an existing single install.